# How do I add a DIV that fits around HTML5 Bootstrap/Boilerplate Fluid container?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html5boilerplate

i just started using bootstrap, and i think it's awesome. but i'm having a hard time figuring out how to add a wrapper around the basic container of bootstrap.

I'm using the Fluid responsive css, and it centers the elements inside the .container nicely.

but my WHOLE page as a whole has a BACKGROUND, and i wanted a different background for the actual content area (where the container is)

So basically i have for example

```
<div id="wrapper-page" style="background-color:grey; ";> 
<div id="wrapper-content" style="background-color:#93C;> 

  <div class="container">Header Contents here </div>
  <div class="container">Body Contents here </div>
  <div class="container">Footer  Contents here </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there a simple way to achieve what i need?

I actually could easily modify the bootstrap.css file to kind of achieve what i want but i really want to keep my modifications outside of the template/framework for easy upgrade later

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the `wrapper-content` also a Bootstrap `.container`?

```
<div id="wrapper-page" style="background-color:grey; " ;=""> 
<div id="wrapper-content" class="container" style="background-color:#93C;"> 

  <div class="container">Header Contents here </div>
  <div class="container">Body Contents here </div>
  <div class="container">Footer  Contents here </div>

</div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://bootply.com/66138)

Comment: hmm before trying that out... i'm interested in actually creating a new style/div for this purpose, not use any of bootstrap's stuff.. this question is actually for a bit more complicated need.. also what if i want to kind of set a MAXIMUM width for the boothstrap containers, and other stuff like that. so i kinda need a wrapper that can just wrap around the container and i'll figure out from there.. and make tweaks or size constraints or what nots